# Python ValueError plot

Tags: python

This is my first time using python (and stackoverflow) , and it keeps showing "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong ?
It is supposed to show three graphs.

```
K,r,a,h,e,m=9,0.5,0.3,0.05,0.1,0.1
def dz(N,P):
    return (r*N*(1-N/K)-a*N*P/(1+a*h*N),e*a*N*P/(1+a*h*N)-m*P)
N0,P0=6,4
pas=10**(-3)
def z(t):
    u,x,y=0,N0,P0
    if t>0 :
        while t-u>pas:
            x,y,u=x+pas*dz(x,y)[0],y+pas*dz(x,y)[1],u+pas
        return x+(t-u)*dz(x,y)[0],y+(t-u)*dz(x,y)[1]
    else :
        while u-t>pas:
            x,y,u=x-pas*dz(x,y)[0],y-pas*dz(x,y)[1],u-pas
        return x+(t-u)*dz(x,y)[0],y+(t-u)*dz(x,y)[1]
def N(t):
    return z(t)[0]
def P(t):
    return z(t)[1]
close()
figure('N(t), P(t), P(N)')
t=linspace(0,15,100)
autoscale(enable=True, axis=u'both', tight=None)
plot(t,N(t),'b--',t,P(t),'r--',N(t),P(t),'k')
axis('scaled')
grid(True)
```

problem solved, please see answers.

Comment: What are `t` and `u` ? At what line does the error occur?

Comment: `t` is an array ... the line `if t > 0:` does not know what to do with that

Comment: i suspect there are other errors. i assume N(t) is a number, so `plot(t,N(t),...)` might not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write some code for exercise first. For example understand how to write and use the functions and what is/are passed to the functions before you begin to write some awesome code. It is what people would say Rome wasn't built in a day.

Back to your code: The way you want the function Z(t) treat t is as a single variable. However, when you use N(t) and call Z(t), t is passed to Z(t) as an array.

Solution: add a for loop after you specify t, to calculate each N(t_i) for each t_i in the array t, and then change the plot part accordingly; alternatively, you have to change the "if else" part in the definition of z(t), into the way that treats t as an array (for example loop through t).

Comment: Ok, i should have known that error. I used to work with a program which does that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you for your solution/comments.

I don't have an error message anymore. And my graphs are showing what they should.

Do you have any tips to make the code faster ? Because it still takes a lot of time to show the graphs (and my very old/slow PC doesn't like that).

Here is the new code (yes, I know, it is really long for such a simple code, but it works) :

```
from pylab import *

K,r,a,h,e,m=20,0.5,0.3,0.05,0.1,0.1
def dz(N,P):
    return (r*N*(1-N/K)-a*N*P/(1+a*h*N),e*a*N*P/(1+a*h*N)-m*P)
N0=10
P0=3
print('conditions initiales :')
print('N0=')
print(N0)
print(' P0=')
print(P0)
pas=10**(-3)
def z(t):
    u,x,y=0,N0,P0
    if t>0 :
        while t-u>pas:
            x,y,u=x+pas*dz(x,y)[0],y+pas*dz(x,y)[1],u+pas
        return x+(t-u)*dz(x,y)[0],y+(t-u)*dz(x,y)[1]
    else :
        while u-t>pas:
            x,y,u=x-pas*dz(x,y)[0],y-pas*dz(x,y)[1],u-pas
        return x+(t-u)*dz(x,y)[0],y+(t-u)*dz(x,y)[1]
def N(t):
    return z(t)[0]
def P(t):
    return z(t)[1]
close()
figure('N(t), P(t), P(N)')
n=100
t=linspace(0,100,n)
N1=zeros(n)
P1=zeros(n)
for i in range(len(t)):
    N1[i]=N(t[i])
    P1[i]=P(t[i])
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,N1,'b--')
title('N(t)')
xlabel('t')
ylabel('N')
autoscale(enable=True, axis=u'both', tight=True)
grid(True)
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(t,P1,'r--')
title('P(t)')
xlabel('t')
ylabel('P')
autoscale(enable=True, axis=u'both', tight=True)
grid(True)
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(N1,P1,'k')
xlabel('N')
ylabel('P')
autoscale(enable=True, axis=u'both', tight=True)
grid(True)
```

Thank you for your help and have a wonderful day.